# re.search not returning strings, but re.findall does

Tags: python, regex, search, findall

I'm getting a bit confused here as to why this is happening. Here's the short and simple code:

```
with open("file.xml") as xmlFile: # reading the xmlFile
    xmlLines=list()
    for line in xmlFile:
        newLine=xmlSearch.findall(line)
        print newLine
```

**RETURNS:** (I changed the actual output for security reasons)

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['TEXT_IN_STRING_FORMAT-SENSITIVE_DATA']
['TEXT_IN_STRING_FORMAT-SENSITIVE_DATA']
['TEXT_IN_STRING_FORMAT-SENSITIVE_DATA']
['TEXT_IN_STRING_FORMAT-SENSITIVE_DATA']
['TEXT_IN_STRING_FORMAT-SENSITIVE_DATA']
['TEXT_IN_STRING_FORMAT-SENSITIVE_DATA']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

However, if I use re.search I get the following:

```
with open("file.xml") as xmlFile: # reading the xmlFile
    xmlLines=list()
    for line in xmlFile:
        newLine=re.search(r"\w/([\w\-]+)",line)
        print newLine
```

(edited output just in case, for security reasons)

```
None
None
None
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000....SNIP>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000....SNIP>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000....SNIP>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000....SNIP>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000....SNIP>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000....SNIP>
None
None
None
None
None
```

Any idea why this is happpening? From the examples I found on Python's docs and on this website, re.search should be returning a string as well. Addding the .groups() at the end results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: No, [it returns a match object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). As for the error… check whether it’s `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.search` returns a `MatchObject` or `None` - See [the `re.search` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

`re.findall` returns a list of strings or tuples - see [the `re.findall` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: I see. I need the results that are coming out of findall. Should I stick to that or is there a way to make re.search convert into a string somehow? I'm guessing findall would be the better way of going about this?

Comment: @Mo2: Why are you considering `re.search`?  What isn't `re.findall` giving you?

Comment: A friend told me to use re.search or re.compile instead so that I get one value instead of a list. That was the only reason I tried to change it, and thus I asked on here. I was just wondering, nothing more.