# repetition in regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've got a file with lines for example:

```
aaa$bb$ccc$ddd$eee
fff$ggg$hh$iii$jj
```

I need to take what is inside $$ so expected result is:

```
 $bb$
 $ddd$
 $ggg$
 $iii$
```

My result:

```
$bb$
$ggg$
```

My solution:

```
m = re.search(r'$(.*?)$', line)
    if m is not None:
        print m.group(0)
```

Any ideas how to improve my regexp? I was trying with * and + sign, but I'm not sure how to finally create it.
I was searching for similar post, but couldnt find it :(

Comment: Technically `ccc` and `hh` are also inside of `$`. Do you want those too?

Comment: Use `.findall` instead of `.search`

Comment: good question, nope I dont want ccc and hh

Comment: I wonder where my comment went. I think the question is not the exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918169/re-search-not-returning-strings-but-re-findall-does because the mere usage of `re.findall` with the current expression does not result in the expected behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with `r'\$[^$]+\$'` regex:

```
import re
line = """aaa$bb$ccc$ddd$eee
fff$ggg$hh$iii$jj"""
m = re.findall(r'\$[^$]+\$', line)
print(m)
# => ['$bb$', '$ddd$', '$ggg$', '$iii$']
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Himvv5)

Note that you need to escape `$`s and remove the capturing group for the `re.findall` to return the `$...$` substrings, not just what is inside `$`s.

**Pattern details**:

- `\$` - a dollar symbol (literal)
- `[^$]+` - 1 or more symbols other than `$`
- `\$` - a literal dollar symbol.

**NOTE**: The `[^$]` is a *negated character class* that matches any char but the one(s) defined in the class. Using a negated character class here speeds up matching since `.*?` lazy dot pattern expands at each position in the string between two `$`s, thus taking many more steps to complete and return a match.

And a variation of the pattern to get only the texts inside `$...$`s:

```
re.findall(r'\$([^$]+)\$', line) 
               ^     ^
```

See [another Python demo](http://ideone.com/2odmAr). Note the `(...)` capturing group added so that `re.findall` could only return what is *captured*, and  not what is *matched*.

Answer (score 3):

`re.search` finds only the first match. Perhaps you'd want `re.findall`, which returns list of strings, or `re.finditer` that returns iterator of match objects. Additionally, you must escape `$` to `\$`, as unescaped `$` means "end of line".

---

Example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\$.*?\$', 'aaa$bb$ccc$ddd$eee')
['$bb$', '$ddd$']
>>> re.findall(r'\$(.*?)\$', 'aaa$bb$ccc$ddd$eee')
['bb', 'ddd']
```

---

One more improvement would be to use `[^$]*` instead of `.*?`; the former means "zero or more any characters besides `$`; this can potentially avoid more pathological backtracking behaviour.

Comment: actually when I use findall expected result is bb, ddd, ggg, iii instead of $bb$, $ddd$, $ggg$, $iii$

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine. [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) only finds the first match in a line. You are looking for [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), which finds all non-overlapping matches. That last bit is important for you since you have the same start and end delimiter.

```
for m in m = re.findall(r'$(.*?)$', line):
    if m is not None:
        print m.group(0)
```